# IMongoCollection calling base class instead of extension method

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

basically, I have a wrapper class for IMongoCollection and I have implemented a few methods

```
 public class MongoCollectionWrapper<T> : IMongoCollectionWrapper<T>
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<T> _mongoCollection;

        public MongoCollectionWrapper(IMongoCollection<T> mongoCollection)
        {
            _mongoCollection = mongoCollection;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to implement the Distinct method, but when I pass the arg Expression<Func<T,TField> which corresponds to the IMongoCollectionExtensions class, It calls the IMongoCollectionBase with the FieldDefition parameter, which obviously does not work,

can someone help me?

The method implementation

```
public IAsyncCursor<TField> Distinct<T, TField>(Expression<Func<T, TField>> field, FilterDefinition<T> filter, DistinctOptions options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            return _mongoCollection.Distinct(field, filter, options, cancellationToken);
        }
```